# How can I convert this AS code in JS?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

Hi guys I have this AS code and I want it in JS is any chance to do it without to write the whole code. I know that are very similar codes but I don't know what I should to change to be JavaScript

```
/ LOCATIONAL
var locationDefinesStandard:Boolean = true
if(slideFrame.beachCheckBox.currentFrame == 2) locationDefinesStandard = false;
if(slideFrame.parkCheckBox.currentFrame == 2) locationDefinesStandard = false;
if(slideFrame.mountainCheckBox.currentFrame == 2) locationDefinesStandard = false;
// standard, mpw, trekking
   var suggestedCar:String;
// DAD
if(parent_Gender == 'Daddy'){
if(number_Kids < 3){
suggestedCar = 'trekking'
}else{
suggestedCar = 'mpw'
}
// MUM
}else {
if(number_Kids > 2){
suggestedCar = 'mpw'
}else{
if(locationDefinesStandard == true){
if(live_location == 'Rural'){
suggestedCar = 'trekking'
}else{
suggestedCar = 'standard'
}
}else{
suggestedCar = 'trekking'
}
}
}
//show result
if(suggestedCar == 'trekking') trekkingFrame.visible = true;
if(suggestedCar == 'standard') largeFrame.visible = true;
if(suggestedCar == 'mpw') mpwFrame.visible = true;
```

Comment: You have to know how to write JS in order to translate to it. The syntax is very similar so it won't be very hard.

Comment: the question is 'is any chance to do it without to write the whole code' the answer is no.

Comment: Your question is too broad, and SO is not a code converting service.  Unless you are using a framework like CreateJS, you cannot just have this work in js.  HTML doesn't have frames and timelines so the vast majority of your code will need to be completely redone based of however you create the visual assets in HTML/js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is near identical. You should only need to change these

```
var suggestedCar: String;
var locationDefinesStandard: Boolean = true
```

To these

<strike>`var suggestedCar = '';`</strike>

```
var suggestedCar = null;
var locationDefinesStandard = true;
```

There are tons of other objects referenced however that I doubt seamlessly will work. For this snippet though, that's all you need for it be valid JS.

Comment: this is not a valid answer to the question and resuming the difference between JS and AS3 to declaring 2 variable is irrelevant. People who voted up and accepted this answer are mistaken as this answer would never server any purpose for anyone. Moreover the supplied comparative syntax is wrong, a non assigned variable of type String in AS3 is null (null is a type and is not a string) while an assigned variable in Javascript is not.

Comment: You mean exactly what I said in the last sentence of my answer?

Comment: that's hardly all he needs to make his code work. How do you translate 'mpwFrame.visible = true', ect ... you just post an answer even though you know there's no answer possible.

Comment: Never said the code would work, I just converted it to JS.